# Instance of 'Graph' has no 'cypher' member - python

Tags: neo4j, graphql, python-3.7

I am trying to connect to Neo4j instance using Py2neo

```
from py2neo import Graph
import re, string

# default uri for local Neo4j instance
graphdb = Graph('http://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7474/db/data')

# parameterized Cypher query for data insertion
# t is a query parameter. a list with two elements: [word1, word2]
INSERT_QUERY = '''
    FOREACH (t IN {wordPairs} |
        MERGE (w0:Word {word: t[0]})
        MERGE (w1:Word {word: t[1]})
        CREATE (w0)-[:NEXT_WORD]->(w1)
        )
'''
```

and load data then apply some cypher commands on the data loaded

```
# load our text corpus into Neo4j
def loadFile():

    tx = graphdb.cypher.begin()
    with open('data/ceeaus.dat', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
        count = 0
        for l in f:
            params = {'wordPairs': arrifySentence(l)}
            tx.append(INSERT_QUERY, params)
            tx.process()
            count += 1
            # process in batches of 100 insertion queries
            if count > 100:
                tx.commit()
                tx = graphdb.cypher.begin()
                count = 0
    f.close()
    tx.commit()
```

Now, the problem is that vscode doesn't recognize *cypher* as a member of *Graph* or doesn't recognize *graphdb* as a *Graph* instance.

The problem is in this line `graphdb.cypher.begin()`
I tried reading the [docs for cypher](https://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html) and found that there exists Cypher member in Graph class; and a begin function in py2neo's cypher.

I am using py2neo v 4.3 and python 3.7 and neo4j v 1.2.4
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `py2neo 4.3`, you need to use the v4 API. You were looking at the v2 documentation.

In py2neo v4, [Graph](https://py2neo.org/v4/database.html#py2neo.database.Graph) does not have a `cypher` method. Instead, you may want to use the `run` method.